# Who should approve changes in curriculum?

Tags: university, united-states, united-kingdom

In the US and UK higher education system, who is responsible for a program curriculum?

For example, if planning to modify the curriculum by adding an uncommon course, who should approve this modification?

Consider that the change is truly uncommon. Can the department head decide about it? or needs the approval of higher officials (such as dean or VP for Academics) or there are boards and committees to decide uncommon changes (for the sake of education quality assurance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proposing a new course or modifying the course requirements for any degree at my university requires several layers of approval:

- The department's (under)graduate study committee
- The tenure-track faculty of the department, by majority vote
- The department head/chair, who transmits the proposal to...
- The college executive committee
- The dean, who transmits the proposal to...
- The campus educational policy committee
- The faculty senate

The last step is usually pro forma; without a formal motion for a vote, the proposal passes automatically.  Each of the other steps (and even the last step, if so moved) requires actual discussion and voting, and the discussion at higher levels is *not* limited to administrative matters as Ben Crowell suggests.

For courses, there is an escape valve called "special topics" courses, which can be offered on an ad hoc basis with only department head/chair approval. Most new courses start as special-topics courses; the formal approvals are only required to give the course its own number.  But special topics courses can't be used as degree requirements.

Comment: Would these courses even count toward basic credit hour requirements?

Comment: @aeismail I assume you mean special topics courses.  It's complicated, but a good approximate answer is "Yes, up to some limit".

Answer (score 3):

In the US, this is a classic example of [shared governance](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18651/1482). Typically there will be a well-defined bureaucratic process for proposing a new course. You write an outline and fill out a bunch of forms. Then the other faculty in your department review it. There will also be layers of approval by managers, but the managers are supposed to be reviewing the course for administrative stuff (e.g., maximum section size, which has fiscal implications), not for content (which is where faculty are the experts).

It's important, especially at a community college, to make a course that will be useful to students if they transfer to another school. E.g., I recently proposed a course, Relativity for Poets, at the community college where I teach, and we wanted to make sure that it would transfer to the state university systems so as to satisfy gen. ed. requirements. At community colleges, these concerns may make it essentially impossible to offer a new and innovative course if there is nothing like it in the state university system.

Assuming that a new course does go through all the approvals, it's still not guaranteed that the school will offer it. For example, they could decide that it's too expensive to offer, or there might not be enough demand.

Comment: so, if it is acceptable from different views, it is the department head who is the final decision maker? When referring to school, you mean it is the department head who decide if it is expensive or without demand to offer?

Comment: @user13854: Different schools have different setups, so the answer to this may depend on what you you mean by "department head." At some schools the department head is a faculty member, at others an administrator. Regarding the content of the course, the final decision is normally made based on a consensus of the faculty who have expertise in the subject matter. If there's a lack of consensus, that probably indicates a problem. E.g., if a significant number of faculty believe that the content is wrong, inappropriate, or not at the college level, then there's a problem with the course.